# Show uniqueness of constants such that this limit is zero

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a smooth function (infinitely differentiable) with domain $\mathbb{R}$. The prompt is to find all real numbers $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-(ax^2+bx+c)}{x^2}=0$$

I have already shown that the numbers $a=\dfrac{f''(0)}{2}, b=f'(0), c=f(0)$ work. However, how can I show uniqueness? In other words, how can I show that no other numbers make the above limit equal to zero?

I can start off by supposing there are numbers $a', b', c'$ such that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-(a'x^2+b'x+c')}{x^2}=0$$

And then I can show uniqueness by showing that $a'=\dfrac{f''(0)}{2}, b'=f'(0), c'=f(0)$. However, I am stuck. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both limits equal zero, then the limit of their difference will also be zero. But their difference is

$$\frac{(a-a')x^2 + (b-b')x + (c-c')}{x^2}.$$

Comment: So it comes down to showing that if $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{px^2+qx+r}{x^2}=0$, then the numerator is the zero polynomial? That is, the constants p, q, and r, are zero.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Yes, that would give you the uniqueness you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to prove this small claim. Would you suggest contradiction? I may be overthinking it.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Yes contradiction would work. If $b \ne b'$ or $c \ne c'$ then you'll have to do some casework to show that the limit is $\infty$ or $- \infty$. If $b=b'$ and $c=c'$ but $a \ne a'$ then the limit is $a-a'\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I see that in some of these cases, the rational function will have a vertical asymptote at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c + r(x)$ for any real numbers $a,b,c$, and the property that you're looking for is

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{r(x)}{x^2} = 0.$$

Hence, you can prove the claim by noticing that $r(x)$ is smooth and computing its first and derivatives at 0, wich is possible by the above limit.